# Qt Transform text

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicstextitem

Is there any way to transform `QGraphicsTextItem` like on  the picture (curve it around the circumference).
[image: Transformation]

I found [QTransform](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtransform.html) class which i can apply by using `QGraphicsItem::setTransform`, but I can't found function to transform text like shown on the picture.

Comment: so [this link](http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/how_do_i_make_text_follow_the_line_curve_and_angle_of_the_qpainterpath) only contains information that you already have and you are simply looking for the functional form?

Comment: Thank you, that link helped me